# AUTOSAR Trusted function in QM application

Tags: rtos, autosar

I understood that trusted function has unrestricted memory access, however I saw that a trusted function is mapped to QM application. Why do we need to put it in QM application if the function is trusted?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the (classic) Autosar OS Standard is quite hard to understand on this:

> The Operating System module shall allow exporting services from
> trusted OS-Applications.

That means with other words, that only trusted OS Applications may provide trusted functions to external callers (like non-trusted OS Applications).

So, when you have a non-trusted OS Application, which has a trusted function configured (which is possible by the structure of the underlying XML), it is not Autosar conform. The generators of Autosar conformant OS implementations should state error messages on this wrong configuration.

You may ask your OS vendor (or the TechRef), whether he uses the configuration container for trusted functions in order to specify something like non-trusted functions in case the owner OS application is non-trusted.

At least MICROSAR OS (Vector) has extra parameters to configure non-trusted functions. Mind, that non-trusted functions are explicitly excluded from the classic Autosar OS Standard.